# Dismissing old UIAlertViewController before presenting new UIAlertViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

> I am new to swift, i want to dismiss the alert which is present on
>   screen when the new alert comes.

I tried:

```
    func showDefaultAlert(controller: UIViewController, title: String, message: String) {

    // create the alert
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

    // add an action (button)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: defaultTextForNormalAlertButton, style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))

    // show the alert
    //controller.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    self.showAlert(controller, alert: alert)

}

func showAlert(controller: UIViewController, alert: UIAlertController) {

        if let currentPresentedViewController = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController?.presentedViewController {
            if currentPresentedViewController.isKindOfClass(UIAlertController) {
                currentPresentedViewController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: {
                    controller.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                })
            }else {

                controller.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }
    }
 }



// Call to above method in view controller class:

SPSwiftAlert.sharedObject.showDefaultAlert(self, title:"Title1", message1: "Message")

SPSwiftAlert.sharedObject.showDefaultAlert(self, title:"Title2", message: "Message2")
```

-
but the above code giving the run time error as :

```
 Attempting to load the view of a view controller while it is deallocating is not allowed and may result in undefined behavior (<UIAlertController: 0x7fceb95dcfb0>)
```

Comment: What's "controller" ? in  controller.presentViewController(alert,...

Comment: check now i have added the whole code.

Comment: aren't you trying to load the same alert you just dismissed?

Answer (score 0):

After presenting the `UIAlertController` you can check its visibility as below:

Presented `UIAlertController`:

```
let alerts=UIAlertController(title: "Test", message: "Test", preferredStyle: .Alert)

presentViewController(alerts, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Check if the `UIAlertController` is visible:

```
if (alerts.isViewLoaded()) 
{
        print("Visible")
        //Here you can dismiss the controller
        //dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

Check out this demo: [Source code](http://speedy.sh/MWRn9/DemoAlert.zip)

Comment: how could i dismiss if the alert is present?

Comment: Just uncomment the line which is added in the code above.
- dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

Comment: check the demo project.